# Url Routing for the page inside a folder in asp.net 4.0?

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to implement Url routing in asp.net 4.0. I just a created a small test application. I am trying to browse the pages kept inside the folder. It works fine when i am running in Visual studio..but when i hosted the application in IIS7 then it showed an error.

**HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.**

The code i used is. (i am using master page too.)

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CustomRouteTable(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

 void CustomRouteTable(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute("Telugu", "Movie/Telugu", "~/Telugu/Telugu.aspx");

    }
```

in my default.aspx page i kept a button and on click of the button i wrote.

```
protected void btnTelugu_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            Response.RedirectToRoute("Telugu");
        }
```

where am i going wrong???
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you updated your web.config to support URL Routing on IIS7.

```
<system.webServer>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">

      <add name="UrlRoutingModule"
             type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, 
                   System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, 
                   Culture=neutral, 
                   PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      <!-- ... -->

    </modules>
    <handlers>

      <add name="UrlRoutingHandler"
            preCondition="integratedMode"
            verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd"
            type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, 
                  System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
                  PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      <!-- ... -->

    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Here is the artice where I c/p the example from, that will give you more details.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347546.aspx

Comment: Ok i updated my config file with the above code?? and i hosted in my IIS under ASP.NET 4.0 (application pool) and it works...But did i need this as it shows the reference of 3.5 and 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void btnTelugu_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Response.RedirectToRoute("Movie/Telugu");
}
```